# Group, sort and select first

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database, nosql

Let's say I have a collection like:

```javascript
{
  couponId: "abc",
  state: "valid",
  date: "2015-11-01"
}
{
  couponId: "abc",
  state: "expired",
  date: "2015-10-01"
}
{
  couponId: "abc",
  state: "invalid",
  date: "2015-09-01"
}
{
  couponId: "xyz",
  state: "invalid",
  date: "2015-11-01"
}
{
  couponId: "xyz",
  state: "expired",
  date: "2015-10-01"
}
{
  couponId: "xyz",
  state: "expired",
  date: "2015-09-01"
}
...
```

a coupon can be valid/invalid/expired.
Now, I want to fetch a list of coupons, where each coupon is selected based on this logic:

- if a "valid" coupon exists, use that
- else if an "expired" coupon exists, use that
- else get the "invalid" coupon.

applying this logic to the above list should yield:

```javascript
    {
      couponId: "abc", /* for "abc" "valid" exists */
      state: "valid",
      date: "2015-11-01"
    },
    {
      couponId: "xyz", /* for "xyz" "valid" does not exist, use the next best "expired" */
      state: "expired",
      date: "2015-11-01"
    }
```

basically, valid > expired > invalid

I have thought of using an aggregate operation, trying to emulate a SQL groupby+sort+selectFirst,

```javascript
db.xyz.aggregate([
  {$sort : { couponId: 1, state: -1 } },
  {$group : { _id : "$couponId", document: {$first : "$$ROOT"} }}
])
```

And obviously this doesn't work, because the "state" field should have a custom sorting where valid>expired>invalid. So, can custom sorting be achieved in an aggregation?

Or is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

A better way, though not that clean/pretty (seems a bit hacky to me :P ), is to nest some **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator expressions with the above criteria/logic in your **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage. Best explained by running the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.xyz.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$couponId",
            "state": {
                "$first": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": ["$state", "valid"]},
                        "$state",
                        {
                           "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": ["$state", "invalid"]},
                                "$state",
                                "expired"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "date": {
                "$first": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": ["$state", "valid"]},
                        "$date",
                        {
                           "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": ["$state", "invalid"]},
                                "$date",
                                {
                                   "$cond": [
                                        { "$eq": ["$state", "expired"]},
                                        "$date", 
                                        "1970-01-01"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "xyz",
            "state" : "invalid",
            "date" : "2015-11-01"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "abc",
            "state" : "valid",
            "date" : "2015-11-01"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking up same thing, on how to translate values on the fly during a query. I tried this, while this works, there is significant impact on the performance. My db has around 1.5m docs, and the actual document is much bigger. Without the 'translation', with default sorting, the time taken is around ~ 0.6s, with the translation/flipping of the fields, the time taken is 4x the first query. As a last resort I may need to change the names or introduce another field...

Comment: I guess you could do with some optimisation to reshape the pipeline for improved performance by including the explain option in the `aggregate()` method. Throw in some `$match` steps at the beginning to filter out unwanted documents, e.g `{ $match: {$state: { $in: ["expired", "invalid", "valid" ] }} }` etc

Comment: I really don't understand how this solution solves the problem, what's the difference between the solution script and just `db.xyz.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$couponId","state":{"$first":"$state"},"date":{"$first":"$date"}}}])`.